# How to determine what ballast for fluorescent lights?

Tags: switches, ac, relay, fluorescent-lamp, ballast

I am creating a UV Cleaner, but this is my first time working with fluorescent bulbs and I wanted to make sure I'm doing it correctly.

I got the following fluorescent bulbs:
[GT15T8 Philips UVC Bulb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026H1S38)

The following ballast: [GE432-MVPS-N](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002B7Q5Q8)

The following connectors for them: T8/T12 Lamp Holder Tombstone

I was reading the ballast operating specs and I don't seem to see anything on it that says that it's compatible with the bulbs, but it supplies the correct amperage and voltage, so I assumed it would work. I haven't yet tried it, but I'm not sure how to tell what kind of ballast I need for a given bulb?

Ideally, the ballast would allow the bulb to be switched on and off pretty regularly with about 10 minutes of runtime in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 15 watt T8 lamp and a ballast for four 32watt T8 lamps. No, it is not the right ballast. The info is in the ballast part number and the description of it in your Amazon link. Just google: 15 watt T8 ballast for the correct one. I came up with Keystone CC579TP or CC 1322TP or Magnetek 200-H2.  I am sure there are many others. Make sure that the one you pick has one  F15T8 in the list of applical bulbs and it does not require a starter.. The first one I listed showed a wiring diagram. The ballast has 2 leads and the bulb has 2 pins on each end. One ballast lead goes to AC, the other goes to a pin on one end of bulb the other pin on that end goes to a pin on the other end of the bulb. The last pin goes to AC. Of course, you probably want to include a power switch.

Comment: Thank you! I've only done arduino level wiring, and nothing with lighting where I needed ballast so this is a huge help!